# Find Top 10 IP out of more than 5GB data

Tags: java, mapreduce

I have a few of files, and total size of them is more than 5 GB. Each line of the files is a IP address, looks like:

> 127.0.0.1 reset success
>
> ...
>
> 127.0.0.2 reset success

how can i find Top10 frequently IP in 25s within 500M memory?
Here is my code,but it takes probably 64s and use more than 1G memory.

```
package main;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;
import java.nio.MappedByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
import java.nio.channels.FileLock;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class TopK {
    public TreeMap<String, Integer> tMap = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();

    public static int MaxLength = 1024 * 1024 * 10;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(12);
        FileHelper fileHelper = new FileHelper(args[0]);
        fileHelper.getFileList(args[0]);
        System.out.println("begin submit: " + LocalTime.now());
        TopK testCountWords = new TopK();
        fileHelper.allFiles.parallelStream().forEach(file -> {
            int count = (int) (file.length() / MaxLength + 1);
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                if (i == count - 1) {
                    CountWords cw = new CountWords(testCountWords, file, i * MaxLength, file.length() - i * MaxLength);
                    executorService.execute(cw);
                } else {
                    CountWords cw = new CountWords(testCountWords, file, i * MaxLength, MaxLength);
                    executorService.execute(cw);
                }

            }
        });

        executorService.shutdown();
        System.out.println("end submit: " + LocalTime.now());
        try {
            while (!executorService.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
                ;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("end count: " + LocalTime.now());
        List<IPAndCount> result = topK(testCountWords.tMap, 5);
        result.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    public static List<IPAndCount> topK(Map<String, Integer> ips, int k) {
        List<IPAndCount> ipAndCounts = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : ips.entrySet()) {
            ipAndCounts.add(new IPAndCount(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
        }

        return ipAndCounts.parallelStream().sorted((ic1, ic2) -> {
            return ic2.getCount() - ic1.getCount();
        }).collect(Collectors.toList()).subList(0, k);

    }

    public synchronized void AddKey(String word) {
        if (tMap.containsKey(word)) {
            tMap.put(word, tMap.get(word) + 1);
        } else {
            tMap.put(word, 1);
        }
    }

}

class CountWords implements Runnable {
    private FileChannel fc;
    private FileLock fl;
    private MappedByteBuffer mbBuf;
    private TopK countWords;
    private RandomAccessFile accessFile;
    public Pattern resetCommandPattern = Pattern.compile(
            "\\s*((?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\\d|((1\\d{2})|([1-9]?\\d)))\\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4]\\d|((1\\d{2})|([1-9]?\\d))))\\s+reset\\s+success",
            Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

    public CountWords(TopK testCountWords, File src, long start, long size) {
        this.countWords = testCountWords;
        try {
            accessFile = new RandomAccessFile(src, "rw");
            fc = accessFile.getChannel();
            // 锁定当前文件的部分
            fl = fc.lock(start, size, false);
            // 对当前文件片段建立内存映射，如果文件过大需要切割成多个片段
            mbBuf = fc.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, start, size);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        String text = Charset.forName("UTF-8").decode(mbBuf).toString();

        Matcher m = resetCommandPattern.matcher(text);

        while (m.find()) {
            countWords.AddKey(m.group(1));
        }
        try {

            // 释放文件锁
            fl.release();
            fc.close();
            accessFile.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            text = null;
        }
        return;
    }
}

class IPAndCount {
    private String ip;
    private int count;

    public IPAndCount(String ip, int count) {
        this.setIp(ip);
        this.setCount(count);
    }

    public String getIp() {
        return ip;
    }

    public void setIp(String ip) {
        this.ip = ip;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public void setCount(int count) {
        this.count = count;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return ip + "," + String.valueOf(count);
    }
}
```

[Here is my code](https://gist.github.com/CherleX/6835fa83ff8ad449b49d827c0bebe091)

Comment: 5GB in 64s is already 80MB/s read speed, are you sure you are not hardware limited? It's already pretty good for HDD. 5GB in 25s would be >200MB/s read speed (without processing time) and would probably require SSD.

Comment: Is this assignment? `awk` would allow you to write code for such task in less than three minutes(although would potentially use over 500MB)

Comment: Are your IP addresses limited to a subset of the address space (e.g., you show only 127.0.0.x addresses in your example) or must the whole address space be supported?

Comment: What's a `FileHelper`?  You neither import nor provide such a class, and your code is incomplete without it.

Comment: If each line of your file has the form you present, then why do you need to match them with a regular expression?  Are you filtering out some of the lines?

Comment: Have you profiled your code to see what parts are consuming the most run time?

Comment: What about making multiple passes through the file? On the first pass, get the IPs and counts for the N [where N is however many you can fit in memory] lexicographically-smallest IPs, discard all but the top 10 counts, and repeat. Ultimately you may end up trading time for space.

Comment: Why the time and memory use limits? Are they arbitrary, or is there some background to them? Fixed numbers like that beg the answer "buy a bigger computer"...

Comment: `tMap.put(word, tMap.get(word) + 1)` - `get` followed by `put` isn't good. `TreeMap` is slow compared to `HashMap`. `ConcurrentHashMap` allows for better concurrency. A `Map` is probably the wrong choice in any case - you should be able to use a ring buffer. Your Regex is far from optimised - if you disable any possibility of backtracking you'll likely gain performance. Keep a global `Pattern` - reuse a `Matcher` on each thread.

Comment: 'FileHelper' is a class used for read file from a dir.Your can get it here[FileHelper](https://gist.github.com/CherleX/503298fc80f1d350f1cc203798eabe5c)

Comment: Because the file have dirty data,so I user regex to filte IP.

Comment: In my solution, bottleneck is IO.'topK' only takes 100-200ms.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yours is an interesting problem, for sure, and problems like this can often be solved better by using more primitive data structures. Additionally, concurrency is often useful, but in IO based input operations your bottleneck is often the IO component, and not the processing.

So, multiple input files may seem like a good thing to parallelize, but the reality is that IO is often sequential. Admittedly, in the current age of SSDs and so on, random access is less of a concern, but I doubt that having parallel IO streams is helping you at all.

So, three major items for you to consider:

1. Remove all concurrency for this problem - your inputs are sequential, and are probably also your bottleneck. You can sequentially read 5GB of data at 100MB/s on a decent HDD in 50 seconds, and on an SSD you can get that done in 10 seconds.
2. Do the work in two operations - one to count each record, and the second to sort the results.
3. Use a better data structure. I would consider using a sparse trie-like primitive `int[][][]` array. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie

The nature of most network-based operation is that almost all traffic comes from a small set of subnets, so your data will be clustered in small number of high-frequency clusters. The array I would use to count in would be something like:

```
private int[][][] counters = new int[1 << 16][][];
```

That creates an array of 65K pointers to `int[][]` arrays. Now, you take your IP addresses, like `127.0.0.1` and the first two bytes `127.0` is the index in to that array. `127.0` is, in hex, `0x7f00`, so make sure that there's an array populated in that location:

```
/**
 * Locate the counter for the given IP address (creating it if necessary) and increment it.
 * @returns the newly incremented count for the given IP.
 */
private static int incrementCount(int[][][] counters, String ipString) {
    // .... ipString = "127.0.0.1"
    byte[] ip = InetAddress.getByName(ipString).getAddress();
    int majorIndex = ip[0] << 8 + ip[1];
    int[][] midTrie = counters[majorIndex];
    if (midTrie == null) {
        midTrie = new int[256][];
        counters[majorIndex] = midTrie;
    }
    if (midTrie[ip[2]] == null) {
        midTrie[ip[2]] = new int[256];
    }
    return ++midTrie[ip[2]][ip[3]];
}
```

OK, so the above function will maintain the counts for each IP address in a primitive data structure, and with little waste of memory. In a worst-case scenario, where you have traffic from every subnet in the planet, you will run out of memory..... but you will have other problems at that point.

So, with the above, you can then build the full set of counters for your data, and after that, you can post-process it and extract the topX count for the IP's.

That topX count is done with a normal mechanism of managing a list of size X containing the IP and count of the largest values.... something like:

```
private static class Candidate {
    private String ip;
    private int count;
    // ....
}

// walk the entire trie of counters, scanning it all.
List<Candidate> topX = new ArrayList<>(x);
for (int i = 0; i < counters.length; i++) {
    if (counters[i] == null) {
        continue;
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < counters[i].length; j++) {
        if (counters[i][j] == null) {
            continue;
        }
        for (int k = 0; k < counters[i][j].length; k++) {
            int count = counters[i][j][k];
            if (count == 0) {
                continue;
            }
            checkCounter(topX, x, i, j, k, count);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, your `checkCounter` method just needs to see whether the count supplied is better than the smallest value already in the topX list, and, if it is, it needs to insert the new value at the correct (sorted) position, and if the list is now larger than size `x`, it should discard the smallest value.

These operations would all be encumbered by concurrency checking, etc.

Comment: I'm always sadly amused when the answer to *"How do I make my <insert-high-level language> code run faster"* is *"Write it as if for a lower-level language"*.  That's often a good answer, to be sure; it's just that too many people fail to understand the tradeoffs they make with choice of language, choice of programming style, etc..  Sometimes even people who should know better make that mistake.  I once had a code review in which I was critiqued for my clean, correct, and fast Java code being written in too C-like a style.

Answer (score 3):

From what I see from the first sight, you don't need TreeMap, because you sort the map anyway afterwards. Don't synchronize when you add to the map and use ConcurrentHashMap instead, it is much faster. But there are probably much more issues there. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Don't sort! This takes your question very literally of taking the top 10, even though your example takes the top 5.

Sort takes `O(n log n)`.

Getting the top record takes `O(n)` getting the top X records is still an `O(n)` operation if X is a constant, this is the big 'Find Top 10' literal assumption.